# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <element> in <parentElement>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a universal ReactJS, I am intentionally rendering different output based on whether the content is rendered by the browser or server to be able to create different controls accordingly. This is done using [`exenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exenv), for example:

```
<section>
  {ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM && (
    <div class="my-super-js-control"></div>
  )}
  {!ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM && (
  <span>Please enable JavaScript if you want the super JS control</span>
  )}
</section>
```

This works well and the result is as expected, however I get a warning in the console:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <section>.
```

From my understanding, after `hydrating` React seems to compare the output HTML string from the server with the one that would be generated on the client-side.

In most cases these would be identical, however in this case I intentionally want different output. What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: The general consensus seems to be, "do this kind of logic in componentDidMount": https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10591

Comment: Perfect thank you. I set my render to show/hide content depending on the state instead of directly accessing `ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM`
and in `componentDidMount` I am running `this.setState({ allowSuperJSControls: ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM });`

Comment: I would use the `<noscript>` html tag for this kind of stuff.